# How is this ageless Data realized?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-data, special-effects, star-trek-picard

Bent Spiner is known to have commented that he couldn't play Data anymore due to his age.

Yet in the recently released trailer for *Star Trek: Picard*, there he is!

Screenshot:
[image]

Was this realized through extreme makeup, a stand-in, CGI, prosthetics, or some combination?

Comment: [There he is!](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/subcultures/cool-cat-saves-the-kids)

Comment: I kind of wonder if that's really Data or if it's B-4 from Nemisis?

Comment: That de-aged data is definitely in the uncanny valley for me!

Comment: Money. Lots of money.

Answer (score 14):

I think, and I admit that this is just speculation, that it's a mix of Spiner wearing an improved version of the Data makeup and *some* digital de-aging but not an entirely CGI character. Data's face in the new pictures looks rounder and softer, closer to how Spiner's looks now, with a much less prominent chin. So if any de-aging is applied, they seem to mostly be using it to smooth up Spiner's face and remove some of the lines, which the makeup also helps to do, but no, I don't think they're using any sort of prosthetics (except for the contact lenses) or lots of CGI (because why not make Data look closer to how he did 17 years ago or even before that?).

EDIT: For the sake of the original question, I (like the OP and most of the fandom) am assuming that Brent Spiner *is* playing Data here and that while this Data might use the *body* of B-4, his neural net/memories/etc are the same as the original's and as such I've elected to refer to the character as Data.

Comment: I don't know.  My guess is that there's a bunch of fake skin applied to parts of his face too.

Comment: Could be some of that, but I'd categorize that as makeup more than actual prosthetics, compared to, say, the elaborate stuff that you have on Worf or that they used for Bib Fortuna and the assorted characters in Star Wars and Planet of the Apes, respectively.

Comment: It could depend on how much money they want to throw at it it. Consider the CGI they used for Nick Fury/Samuel L. Jackson in Captain Marvel. Also, keep in mind that it probably isn't Data you are seeing. He died in the movie Nemesis remember? It's more likely to be his brother, B-4.

Comment: @AllanMills Well yes it's probably B-4's body, but it's not B-4's mind, it's Data's. After all, our thoughts and memories and personalities are what make us truly human. 'Course, I'm kinda hoping they'll explore that a little. Star Wars tried it with Callista/Cray in a few of the EU books and... didn't reeeally succeed.

Comment: @SpaceWolf1701 I don't see they specifically state it is Data in the clip though. Picard mentions losing Data and he shows a disassembled Data type android. The "Data" who speaks in the clip could be B-4 though but he might be more Data like since Data uploaded his memories into him. Keep in mind though, he'd have something like a different OS.

Comment: @AllanMills, I'm wondering whether "I don't want the game to end" hints a holodeck is involved.   Although I do admit this seems to be contradicted by the disassembled android.

Comment: Actually, I think this is definitely the case, since "Data" says, "I can see that, **Captain**".     If this Data were current, he would call Picard "Admiral".

Comment: @ThePopMachine To be fair, Picard left Starfleet sometime after being promoted to Admiral. And that one (Vulcan?) character tells Picard to "be the Captain they remember". Since it doesn't seem like Picard is part of Starfleet anymore (no uniform), it might be that he no longer holds an official rank and "Captain" refers to being leader-of-a-ship-crew instead of an actual Starfleet Captain? Not to mention that Seven takes a rather brusque tone with him that I don't think anyone would do if he was still Admiral Picard. Even Admiral Kirk didn't get that sorta reaction!

Comment: @SpaceWolf1701, this is really pushing it.   A retired Admiral is referred to as Admiral.

Comment: @ThePopMachine Generally speaking, yes, but I disagree that it's "really pushing it" to not call Picard "admiral" when he's not acting in a capacity as a Starfleet Admiral. It might be that we're both right, after all; that it's a fake (hologram or otherwise) Data calling him "Captain" and that Picard's elected to be called "Captain" by his selected crew. We'll just have to wait and see!

Comment: @ThePopMachine The Captain of a Ship is *always* referred to as "Captain" - regardless of whether their *rank* is Captain, Admiral, Commander, or even an NCO.  (This actually comes up in DS9, when Commander Sisko captains the Defiant)  So, there is **a lot** depending on other context we don't see surrounding that scene.

Comment: @Chronocidal, an Admiral, even as a captain of the ship, will be rather referred to as an Admiral. In all other cases, you are right.